# Insert citation doesn't work

Tags: citation-management

I have both Mathematica (10.3 Student Version) and EndNote (X7) installed on my Windows 7. According to the documentation, I should be able to insert bibilographic references to a text cell of a notebook if EndNote is running. However, when I choose

Insert -> Citation -> Bibliographical Note

then, instead of seeing all the citations which I have already imported into my EndNote library, I only see an empty window. Anyone having some advice what is wrong? I am not sure from the description that the EndNote plug-in, which Mathematica needs, is installed automatically when I install EndNote, or something else need to be done.

Comment: You're getting further than I am, when I try and insert a citation Mathematica crashes.

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the same problem, and found a temporary solution. As we known, mathematica use MathEndnote.dll  to link with EndNote, but it is located in the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ResearchSoft\EndNote\Plugins" which may be used by old version of EndNote, and EndNote X7 install path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\EndNote X7\Plugins". So I simply copy the dll file from the old path to new fold, and although it shows some error note, it does works.